# Why does Socket.io not connect when I put the SSL certificate?

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, websocket, livecharts

I have client socket.io js and backend phpsocket.io, I can do it on a server without a domain, making use of the IP nothing else and it works for me, it sends and receives information, but when I mount it on a server with a domain, it never send nothing. I have enabled TCP port 2300, and I use AWS as a server. I have done many tests in production with a server without domain and without certificate and everything goes well, but it is when it has the certificate it fails.

Client code where I run the js to connect from local to the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    const idusuario= "<?=$this->idusuario?>";

    const socket = io.connect('https://myserver.muestra.com:2300', {secure: true});
    console.log(idusuario);
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        socket.emit('add user', idusuario);
    });

    $('.msg1').click(function (){
        console.log('clickeado 1++**********');
        console.log(idusuario);
        socket.emit('add user', idusuario);
    });



    $('.msg2').click(function (){
        console.log('clickeado 2');
        socket.emit('chat message', '<?=session_id()?> HOLA');
    });

    $('.msg3').click(function (){
        console.log('clickeado 3');
        socket.emit('allusers');
    });

    $('.msg4').click(function (){
        console.log('clickeado 4');
        socket.emit('allusersobject');
    });

    socket.on('chat message', data => {
        console.log(data)
    });
    socket.on('user joined', data => {
        console.log(data)
        /*console.log(JSON.parse(data));*/
    });
    socket.on('user left', data => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(idusuario);
        console.log(data.idusuario);
        var usuarioeliminado = JSON.parse(data.idusuario)
        if (idusuario===usuarioeliminado.idusuario) {
            console.log('SON IGUALES');
            socket.emit('add user', $('.iduser').val());
        }
    });

    socket.on('allusers', data => {
        console.log(data);
    });

    socket.on('allusersobject', data => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data.numUsers))
        console.log(JSON.parse(data.users))
    });




</script>
```

I also have this in the backend, which I use to get the queries running and where I keep the users.

```
require_once 'config/config.php';
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$io = new SocketIO(2300);

$io->on('connection', function ($socket) {
$socket->addedUser = false;
// when the client emits 'new message', this listens and executes
$socket->on('new message', function ($data) use ($socket) {
    // we tell the client to execute 'new message'
    $socket->broadcast->emit('new message', array(
        'username' => $socket->username,
        'message' => $data
    ));
});

// when the client emits 'add user', this listens and executes
$socket->on('add user', function ($username) use ($socket) {
    global $usernames, $numUsers;


    // remove the username from global usernames list

    if (isset($usernames[$username])):
        unset($usernames[$username]);
        --$numUsers;
    endif;


    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $sql = "select idusuario,nickname from usuarios where idusuario = $username";
    $usuario = $conexion->getdato($sql);


     
    $socket->username = $usuario;
     
    $usernames[$username] = $username;
    ++$numUsers;
    $socket->addedUser = true;
    $socket->emit('login', array(
        'numUsers' => $numUsers
    ));
    // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
    $socket->broadcast->emit('user joined', array(
        'username' => json_encode($usernames),
        'numUsers' => $numUsers
    ));
});

 
$socket->on('typing', function () use ($socket) {
    $socket->broadcast->emit('typing', array(
        'username' => $socket->username
    ));
});

 
$socket->on('stop typing', function () use ($socket) {
    $socket->broadcast->emit('stop typing', array(
        'username' => $socket->username
    ));
});
$socket->on('allusers', function () use ($socket) {
    global $usernames, $numUsers;
    
    $socket->broadcast->emit('allusers', array(
        'users' => json_encode($usernames),
        'numUsers' => $numUsers
    ));
});


$socket->on('allusersobject', function () use ($socket) {
    global $usernames, $numUsers;
     
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $users = [];
    foreach ($usernames as $item) {

        $sql = "select idusuario,nickname,idroll from usuarios where idusuario = $item";
        $users[] = $conexion->getdato($sql);
    }
    $socket->broadcast->emit('allusersobject', array(
        'users' => json_encode($users),
        'numUsers' => $numUsers
    ));
});


 
$socket->on('disconnect', function () use ($socket) {
    global $usernames, $numUsers;
           

    if ($socket->addedUser) {
        unset($usernames[$socket->username->idusuario]);
        --$numUsers;

        // echo globally that this client has left
        $socket->broadcast->emit('user left', array(
            'username' => $socket->username,
            'numUsers' => $numUsers,
            'idusuario' => json_encode(['idusuario'=>$socket->username->idusuario])
        ));
    }




   });

  });

  if (!defined('GLOBAL_START')) {
   Worker::runAll();
  }
```

Everything indicates that it would be something related to the certificate or cloudflare.

Comment: Is it a self signed certificate? Often you find issues with non-authoritative sourced certificates.

Comment: it is not a self-signed certificate.